# write complete JSON of different lengtsh to column in SQL using Informatica BDM

Tags: sql, sql-server, informatica

For a job project I am using informatica BDM to read in JSON-files from an ADLS folder, the goal is to write the complete JSON file as a string in a single column in SQL server.

I made a new table in SQL server with the target column being a varchar(max).

Next to this I made a simpe mapping flow with a read and write transformation, however, I notice that SQL server cutts of the JSON after 8000 characters and saves the next 8000 characters in a new row, the next 8000 in the next row etc etc.

For a file consisting of 50.000 characters it now saves 6 rows of 8000 characters in the SQL database and does not save the last 2000 characters.

Does anybody have an idea how i can solve this problem?

thanks in advance!

Comment: *"I notice that SQL server cutts of the JSON after 8000 characters and saves the next 8000 characters in a new row, the next 8000 in the next row etc etc."* No it doesn't. What is the SQL you have here? Take the time to provide us with a [mre].

Comment: Hello @Larnu, thank you for your answer. I understand what you mean, a SQL column can hold more than 8000 character. However, in this specific example, I think informatica BDM does something that cutts of the column to 8000 charaters. I added a printscreen of informatica mapping and the outcome of SQL

Comment: You've not added anything to the question?